# Delete symbol (number, space, dot, comma) in string SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a string like a address.
How delete all symbols (number, space, dot, comma) from start and end of string?

*For example:*
Obere Str**. 57**
**120** Hanover Sq**.**
*to->* 
Obere Str
Hanover Sq

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find answer:
`select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(address, '[0-9\. ,]+$',''),'^[0-9\. ,]+','')
from customers`

Answer (score 0):

example :

```
SELECT employee_id, REPLACE(job_id, 'SH', 'SHIPPING') FROM employees
WHERE SUBSTR(job_id, 1, 2) = 'SH';
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sql.htm 
Chapter 3-18

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace(the_column, '[0-9\. ,]+','')
from the_table;
```

or if you actually want to change the data in the table:

```
update the_table
  set the_column = regexp_replace(the_column, '[0-9\.]+','');
```

Comment: This is not full correctly, because if string "Obere Str. 57" after return "OberSt". But your answer help me find the answer on the question. Thks